# How to read secure web requests and process web socket requests with a single Java ServerSocket?

Tags: java, server

**Intro**

My code can process all bytes that are sent to a server and decide whether or not to let them go through and eventually send responses. I would like to use this to use the server as web server, web socket server and tcp server in one.

Although my code is written for Minecraft, I am not asking this on a Minecraft forum because answering this question doesn't require any prior knowledge about Minecraft or its codebase.

**All you need to know about Minecraft**

Minecraft is a Java game that can be played online. When it is being played online, there is a server that opens a ServerSocket and all players have their own client that opens a Socket that will communicate with the ServerSocket of the server.

Anyone can create a Minecraft server and install server-side modifications on their server (for those who know Minecraft, these are usually called plug-ins). My application is such a server-side modification. Most Minecraft servers are being hosted by Minecraft host companies. The owners of the servers have some kind of access to the part of the host computer that manages the server files.

**Goal**

The goal of my modification is to let the Minecraft server serve more clients than just the Minecraft clients. I would like the same server to also work as web server (for http and https requests) as well as (secure) web socket server and tcp server.

**Why no multiple server sockets**

The most common solution would be to just create a ServerSocket for the other server types and assign a different port to all of them. However, that is not an option in my case. Most hosts forbid you to open other ports or ask extra money for it. So I need to do it all with just the Minecraft ServerSocket.

**What I achieved so far**

So far, I have managed to let all bytes that are sent to the minecraft server first go through my code. My code can choose whether or not to let the bytes continue to the Minecraft server code. It can also send responses on its own without the need to inform the Minecraft server code at all.

In principle, what I have managed to do is sufficient to accomplish my goal, but I would like some help with how to continue. I will explain below what I have and have not accomplished so far.

The first byte that is sent by a Minecraft client to the server is always the same, namely 16. This is great because it allows me to easily distinguish Minecraft clients from web browsers and tcp clients.

HTTP requests and websocket connections always start with the same byte, namely 71. HTTPS and secure websockets always start with the byte 22. The TCP connections I was talking about will be sent by my own applications, so I can choose exactly what bytes they will send and I can simply program my modification to respond to that.

I managed to distinguish http requests and websocket connections by their connection property. Http requests always send 'Connection: keep-alive' while websocket connections always send 'Connection: upgrade'. (Although some browsers do the k, a and u in uppercase and others do not.)

Handling normal http requests wasn't very hard to do. Handling TCP connections won't be hard either because I will control everything. But I have issues with the remaining connection types:

**Problems I need help with**

The web socket protocol is quite large and I would prefer not to handle it completely with only my code. (I tried this before, but I kept having problems with the parts that were rarely used and thus not tested.) So I would like to use some library that allows me to only worry about the payload rather than the entire protocol. Unfortunately, web socket libraries generally want to create the ServerSocket, which is not possible in my case. **So does anyone have advice on what to do here?**

I haven't found any info on how to read https requests properly. **Could someone tell me where to look for the details of this protocol or provide a nice link?**
For secure web sockets, I will face the same problems as with the 'normal' web socket connections after I find out how to read the requests.

**Code**

All my code so far can be found at https://github.com/knokko/Multi-Purpose-Server. The most interesting part is probably the part where my code gets the opportunity to process all bytes before they arrive at the Minecraft code, that code is shown below.

**Short question(s)**

For those who didn't understand exactly what my question (you could see it as 2 questions that are strongly related) is:

-How I should read https requests and secure web socket handshakes?

-Does anyone know a library that can handle web socket input that doesn't require to create the ServerSocket itself?

```
// This channel handler will be registered for every connection client that will
                    // inspect
                    // any message before it reaches the Minecraft code.
                    pipeline.addFirst("multipurpose_handler_inspector", new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {

                        private boolean deactivated;

                        private ChannelListener listener;

                        @Override
                        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                        //super.channelRead will send the content to the minecraft code
                            try {
                                if (!deactivated) {
                                    ByteBuf message = (ByteBuf) msg;
                                    if (listener != null) {
                                        listener.read(ctx, message);
                                    } else {
                                        byte firstByte = message.getByte(0);

                                        // All Minecraft connections start with the byte 16
                                        if (firstByte == 16) {
                                            deactivated = true;
                                            super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                                        }

                                        // All insecure web connections start with the byte 71
                                        else if (firstByte == 71) {
                                            byte[] data = new byte[message.readableBytes()];
                                            message.getBytes(0, data);
                                            WebHandler.Type type = WebHandler.determineConnectionType(data);
                                            if (type == WebHandler.Type.HTTP) {
                                                listener = new HTTPListener();
                                                listener.readInitial(ctx, message);
                                            } else if (type == WebHandler.Type.WEBSOCKET) {
                                                // TODO Find a nice way to handle web socket connections
                                                listener = new WebSocketListener();
                                                listener.readInitial(ctx, message);
                                            } else {
                                                deactivated = true;
                                                super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        // All secure web connections start with the byte 22
                                        else if (firstByte == 22) {
                                            // TODO implement the secure web protocols and find a way to read this stuff
                                            // and find the difference
                                            System.out.println(
                                                    "We are dealing with a secure websocket or https connection");
                                            byte[] data = new byte[message.readableBytes()];
                                            message.getBytes(0, data);
                                            System.out.println(new String(data));
                                        }

                                        // My applications
                                        else if (firstByte == 31) {
                                            listener = new TCPListener();
                                            listener.readInitial(ctx, message);
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("Unknown connection type");
                                            deactivated = true;
                                            super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Might I suggest summarizing your question into the title?  Your title is not a question, it's a description (as is most of your question).

Comment: @Bill K Would this title be better? (I am having trouble with explaining everything faster, so the 'question' is indeed mostly explanation and quite long.)

Comment: Better--I still can't tell exactly what you want.  Would it make sense to say "With a shared socket, how can I process https requests" (if that's what you are asking).  It's a difficult problem by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you can ALWAYS identify the Minecraft traffic, your best bet might be to run an apache/httpd and/or tomcat server on the same box and forward all non-Minecraft traffic to it.  If you do this, the HTTPS stuff might just be a matter of correctly configuring the http server for https traffic.

You may have to configure your code as an http proxy--in fact (Just thought of this) you might want to go out and look for an open source http proxy and just tweak it with your code to extract Minecraft traffic and forward it before doing the rest of the proxy stuff.

I wouldn't do the HTTPs stuff from scratch, it's not terribly difficult but I'd call it non-trivial.

Oh and if your problem is "differentiating Minecraft HTTPS traffic from other HTTPS connections on the same port" I can't help except to say that this might be a good subject for your question :)

Comment: I can indeed ALWAYS identify the Minecraft traffic. But how exactly should I execute the tomcat/apache approach? I can't let those servers actually start their own server, so I would have to give them some kind of fake port and let my application/modification send the data to those fake ports and. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You would give them a port that isn't accessible outside the box and you would forward all the traffic to that port.  That's why I recommended copying what an HTTP proxy does because you'd be doing almost exactly that (with the exception of extracting the Minecraft traffic).  The reason I suggest the proxy/server approach is that I think they may have solved problems you haven't encountered yet.